# Git GUI on Windows not seeing .git folder from Samba share

Tags: linux, virtualbox, git, samba, vagrant

**THE SCENARIO**
I am using Vagrant,Windows environment and running Ubuntu inside the virtual box for my development work. I have setup an instance of Samba server and I run the I access the virtual machine through vagrant and Git Bash and run the command 
`net use A: \\192.168.91.11\www vagrant /persistent:no /user:vagrant`
in windows cmd. This creates a virtual drive in Windows and I can access all the linux files from windows. Git related operations run fine with the Bash CLI. I want to try and setup a Git GUI like TortoiseGit.

**THE PROBLEM**
I am not able to see the `.git` folder inside the virtual drive.
I have already tried to change the folder options to show hidden folders, show archives, remove the readonly on the drive, but still the `.git` folder remains hidden. The `.git` folder is visible when I run the ll command on the CLI. However it remains hidden when I access the virtual drive from windows.
I wonder if there even is a way to use a gui in this setup. Excuse the long description but I need some advice here. If there is any other way to implement a GUI in this setup, I'm all ears! Thanks.

***EDIT***
[image]
So I cloned my repository and on viewing the list, I see the `.git` folder as shows in the screen shot above.
[image]
But when I see the same folder in the virtual drive, it does not show up. I have already set the required properties like show archives, hidden files and unchecked readonly.

Comment: attach screenshot, how you are trying to access it?

Comment: Updated my post @SeanClt. Also as suggested in the below answer, I have set the `hide dot files = no`.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but maybe this answer could help somebody in the future (eg. like me 1 hour ago )

This happens because Git sees the repository as unsafe because it is owned by somebody else.

To add an exception for this directory, run this command in your Windows machine:

```
$ git config --global --add safe.directory '%(prefix)///192.168.91.11/path-to-samba-shared-repo'
```

After that you should be able to run `git` commands in that repository from Windows. I just tried with `git gui` and `gitk`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.git` files are likely hidden by the `hide dot files` option on the share.  It defaults to `true`.

Try adding a line to the share specification like:

```
hide dot files = false
```

This should take effect within seconds after you change the configuration.

Comment: In the smb.conf file, I see the line `hide dot files = no` which I think means is already set to show. Tried to change it to false but to no effect. @BillThor is there a way to maybe add multiple valid users in this file. Currently it shows `valid users = vagrant`. Maybe I add the windows user to it?

Comment: @Aditya  valid users is a list you can list multiple users.  However, valid groups may be a more appropriate way to solve that issue.  You may need to use other options to set and use the appropriate permissions.  Please read the man page.